# How to post jquery ajax data object with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with two inputs (later more inputs). One input is a text input and the second one is a checkbox. I would like to send these two inputs with $.ajax.

I created an Object `formData` with one input. The second one I would like to append to the Object if the checkbox is active or not.

Unfortunately, I can't pass the Object because of a wrong format.

My Code:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by a name">
<input type="checkbox" name="exact" value="Exact">Exact
</form>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myForm').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                console.log($(this).val() + ' is now checked');
            }
            else {
                console.log($(this).val() + ' is now unchecked');
            }
        });

        var formData = {'qry':search};
        $('#search_text').on('keyup', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var search = $(this).val();
            $('#result').html('');
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  need to serialise the form data and then add more data if required:

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'sample', value: "something_more"});
```

Your ajax should then be something like:

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'sample', value: "something_more"});
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "text",
            processData: false, 
            success:function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thats a cool solution. But i have a Livesearch function (keyup) and i can't it implement